# "GAZE" GUI Organizer program?

Tags: ms-dos, identify-this-software

In the early-to-mid '90s there was a GUI-based DOS organizer-like program, called GAZE, from which you could launch software and games which had an eyeball in the corner that followed the cursor as you moved it. It was simple gray and white panes with black text.

Any ideas or is this total vaporware?

Comment: I know a DOS menu called Glance (https://www.mrdictionary.net/dos/gl0192.png) but no memories of Gaze.

Comment: Gaze is the precursor to Glance if I'm remembering right. I'll look into it. Don't believe there were any eyes involved though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Gaze* is available on [retroarchive.org](http://www.retroarchive.org/cdrom/garbo_dos/menu/index.html) as `gaze10ur.zip`. It's a graphical menu for DOS that lets you make a set of shortcuts to DOS programs and organise them into groups. You can configure the six icons at the bottom to have any function as well (though you can only pick the icons from a list rather import your own).

It's by the same author as *Glance*, and it explicitly described as its successor in the docs. The eyes in the corner don't follow the cursor around but they do blink.

(*Gaze* is interesting, but imo *Glance* is far superior: clearer, easier to use, smaller. Use *Glance* if you want an attractive, easy-to-use tiled menu, or *LaunchBox for MS-DOS Special Edition 2.0* if you want a sortable list with developer/publisher/year/etc metadata fields.)

[image]
[image]